# getting unique user number for visited_pages in sql how?

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

My table is Person. I am trying to get unique user number for each visited page, but I cant find to use distinct, count and group by at the same query. Do you have any solution guys ??

Persons:

| user | visit_page_no |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 66 |
| 11 | 66 |
| 11 | 66 |
| 44 | 66 |
| 55 | 66 |
| 55 | 77 |
| 99 | 77 |
| 33 | 88 |

Wanted result:

| visited_page_no | count |
| --- | --- |
| 66 | 3 |
| 77 | 2 |
| 88 | 1 |

Comment: Do you need a solution for both `mysql` and `tsql`? As you can see from the tag descriptions they are usually mutually exclusive.

Comment: Please edit to improve the grammar of the question. Also, the feedback from @HABO is very useful. Also, you write ‘I am trying to get unique user number for each visited page’. How exactly? It is not always necessary to provide sample code, but it is often helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `count(distinct)`:

```
select visit_page_no, count(distinct user)
from t
group by visit_page_no;
```